# Android adding fragment in drawer layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having some difficulties when trying to use a navigation drawer and fragment together.

**main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GoogleMap" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So the problem that I am facing is the navigation drawer only shows the content for a short moment when I rotate the device either from portrait to landscape or the other way around. The navigation drawer will remains empty if I do not tilt the device.

The fragment is basically a so-called div to show a map. Then when I click on the navigation drawer, it will be on the top of the map fragment. I wonder which part of my layout went wrong and causing this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited Portion**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

GoogleMap.java

```
public class GoogleMap extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap map;

    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        // App Icon 
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                );

        // Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

        // just styling option add shadow the right edge of the drawer
        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
        // then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
         actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(GoogleMap.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=1.3564 ,103.8311&daddr=1.3426 ,103.9254"));
            //startActivity(i);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

        }
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(1.32814,103.80679) , 11.0f) );

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (map == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one Problem with your Layout(i don't know others!) which is using DrawerLayout inside a LinearLayout , `DrawerLayout` should be **root view** in your Layout file.

Comment: So basically I supposed to set drawerLayout as root view. Then inside the linearLayout, I should put fragment and the listView?

Comment: @20Cents : yes you can , but also you can use a FrameLayout inside your DrawerLayout and make your Fragment dynamically

Comment: I changed it already. Check my edited portion but the problem still remain.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 views directly inside your drawerlayout. The drawer must only have 2 views immediately inside it. I'd recommend wrapping the fragment and framelayout inside a linearlayout or relativelayout. Either that or nest the fragment inside the framelayout

Comment: So basically I supposed to set drawerLayout as root view. Then inside the linearLayout, I should put fragment and the listView?

Answer (score -1):

You should code like this:

> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
>  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"      
>  android:layout_width="match_parent"          
>  android:layout_height="match_parent">            
>  <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>   <!-- The navigation drawer -->    
>   <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"    
>     android:layout_width="240dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"    
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"    
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp"    
>     android:background="#111"/>        
> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```

**Edit:**
And in your `Activity` set the fragment in this `FrameContent`.

In your onCreate() add this line

> if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>                initilizeMap();
>           }

Comment: see the sample code of default NavigationDrawer here [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: in my Activity set the fragment as in? Could you please provide me some solution based on my codes? I will update the question

Comment: create a `FragmentActivity` class in your `Activity` and inside `FragmentActivity's` onCreateView() inflate your `Fragment` on `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I did in this way: LinearLayout linearLayout; 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
   linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
            return rootView;
        }  ,but it does not work. Would you mind to provide me a solution? cause I am really lost.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve that problem. The content still only show after I rotate the screen.